# Cannot get image to have correct border-radius

Tags: html, css

I have an image with some text-overlay for a menu. However, the image does not get the appropriate border-radius and I can't figure out why.

I want the image and overlay to have a rounded edge like `border-radius: 8px;` however everything I have tried doesn't work. I've tried putting `!important` and setting the border radius on all parent elements as well.

Here is a link the code in stackblitz. According to my research, it might have something to do with images inside a div.

(BTW, I'm using angular, but I've simplified the html)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mat-beta-12-fzsfeh?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html

[image: html problem]

[image: html problem with dev tools highlight]

Comment: [mcve] in your question please

Comment: the example is not working. post the generated html that you can see in your browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unset padding for `<img class="groupPic" src="https://i.imgur.com/ZmqcZAx.jpg" [alt]="'Photo of ' + group">`
and unset margin-top for `<div class="flexHeader">`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xEx5.png)

Comment: Thank you, that worked! So what I'm learning is that if you want a border-radius on the image, then you can't have padding on the edge where the border-radius is?

Comment: @MarcusGallegos Well if you set a border on the image like `border: 1px solid red` and still have the padding, you see that the border-radius is actually applied. However you won't be able to see the result because the `padding` is curved. `Padding` is inside the border, `margin` is outside the border